# ssh tunnel between servers

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to create an ssh tunnel (socks5) with this schema to pass all traffic through C

`A -> B -> C -> net`

A: My client
B: Server-1
C: Server-2

How can I do this scenario with the ssh command?